# Appoggiaturas not playing in Noteflight audio

Tags: software, audio, ornaments, noteflight

I have arranged *Für Elise* in Noteflight with two 16th note appoggiaturas circled in red. I expect them to play in the audio but they don't (unlike acciaccaturas which do play).

[image: Excerpt of Für Elise in Notiflight. Immediately after a second volta repeat, there is a two 16th note appoggiatura (circled)]

The bar with the appoggiaturas sounded like this (without the appoggiaturas):

[image: Close up of the bar with the appoggiatura from above, but without the appoggiatura.]

I would expect them to sound like this:

[image: Close up of the bar with the appoggiatura from above, with the appoggiatura.]

Is there a way to make the appoggiaturas play in the audio? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So by default, both appoggiaturas and acciaccaturas play with audio in Noteflight, so something seems to be going wrong. Here is an example of me constructing an appoggiatura and the resulting audio:

So in resolving this, the first thing I would recommend is to try deleting the current appoggiatura you have in your score, and then re-entering the appoggiatura the way I did, and see if it solves the issue. (Make sure to input the appoggiatura using only the mouse, as there may be a bug with another input method causing this issue)

If not, I would next recommend creating an appoggiatura in a new, blank score. If it works in this new score, but not in the original score, that would show that there may be an issue with the settings in the original score, or that some other form of input was used in the original score that is causing an issue, and then we could move on from there!

(It is interesting to note, that Noteflight has no built-in feature for muting individual notes or setting either of the grace note styles to not play audio.)

(I would also ask, if neither of these options work, are you using Noteflight premium, or the standard version of Noteflight?)

Comment: It still didn't work.

Comment: Okay, first question, do you have Noteflight premium or are you using the free version?

Comment: I am using the free version.

Comment: Good to know, that at least rules out modifying settings in the premium version to see if that results in a bug fix. The next question would be, what web browser are you using for Noteflight?

Comment: Google Chrome is what I am using

Comment: In my new score, the appoggiaturas did play.

Comment: Fantastic, that means there isn't an issue with the account or the web browser, but just something in that particular score. So we at least have the option to move over to a new score. But let's try and see if we can get it to work in the current score. Could you try adding a new measure at the end of the score, and then add an appoggiatura there, to see if it plays any sound?

Comment: I had figured out that the appoggiaturas did align with the left-hand 16th note arpeggio.

Comment: The appoggiaturas are played as acciaccaturas in recordings, I think. Why did Beethoven use appoggiaturas to represent acciaccaturas?

Comment: @Vighnesh Single unslashed grace notes are usually appoggiatura.  When they have a slash through them they are acciaccatura. But multiple note acciaccatura usually don't have the slash for some reason.